# Discord.js - if message includes, case insensitive

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to block swear words using my Discord Bot. So, I've created a JSON file of the ones I want to block and named it `swear_words`. As a test, I've added sware to test. Then I include it at the top of my `bot.js` file:

```js
const { swear_words, mute_content } = require(`./swear-words.json`);
```

And then my blocking code, at the bottom:

```js
client.on(`message`, message => {
    for (var i=0; i < swear_words.length; i++) {
        if (message.content.includes(swear_words[i])) {
            message.delete();
            message.channel.send(mute_content);
            console.log("Someone tried to swear.");
        }
    }
});
```

That works when I type `sware`, but not `Sware`. So I add `swear_words.prototype.toLowerCase()` to make:

```js
if (message.content.includes(swear_words.prototype.toLowerCase() === swear_words[i])) {}
```

and then I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

What is this? Can it not read my JSON?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What do you expect `prototype.toLowerCase()` to do?

Comment: convert the entire message to lowercase

Comment: You should break your loop if you encounter something. No need to send same mute command multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.toLowerCase( )` on the message content, as it returns a string.

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase( ).includes(swear_words[i])) {
```

Comment: That removes the error and blocks `sware` but doesn't really fix my main issue, because `Sware` is still blocked